# Chrome Android considers only one media query

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, media-queries

I'm actually having a problem with media queries on Chrome Android.
I have one file (mobile.css) containing the mobile design for the header and the footer. This file is imported in every page and the media query in it is the following :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    /* some code */
}
```

Each page of my website then has its proper css file containing the mobile design relative to this page, the media query is the same as in the mobile.css file.

This code works fine on desktop Chrome and Firefox and on Firefox Android but it doesn't work at all on Chrome Android and I can't figure out why.

**UPDATE**

I changed one of the media query to :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 981px) {
    /* some code */
}
```

and it works. Apparently Chrome Android doesn't like when there are two same queries ... It's not very elegant but it works.

Comment: *"I can't figure out why"*.. I explained why but you will evidently learn the hard way if you don't take advice.. look at media queries in the source code of any webpage and you'll see that they are styled as I suggested. Happy learning!

Comment: You explained how to style media queries and I thank you for that. Now my question was why was it not working on Chrome Android, question you did not answer. So please calm down and stop looking down on me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed one of the media query to :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 981px) {
    /* some code */
}
```

and it works. Apparently Chrome Android doesn't like when there are two same queries ... It's not very elegant but it works.